# Button Click Events on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, mobile

i I have a button on a webpage. The page is only going to be viewed on mobile devices. everything seems to load fine; however, there are some controls on the page. Two date pickers and a button to submit the two dates and present new data. I have a javascript function that works fine on a computer but nothing happens when the button is clicked on a phone. Here is the javascript code.

```
  function getURL() {
        var from = $("#fromDate").val();
        var to = $("#toDate").val();
        from = from.replace("/", "%2F");
        to = to.replace("/", "%2F");

        $(".toDTP").val("");
        $(".fromDTP").val("");

        window.location.href("http://the new url.aspx?from=" + from + "&to=" + to);
```

here is the HTML:

```
  <label for="date">From:</label><input type="date" name="date" id="fromDate" value="" />
                <label for="date">To:</label><input type="date" name="date" id="toDate" value="" />

                <a class="FilterCalendar" id="fetchCalendar" href="javascript:getURL()">Fetch Data</a>
```

what is going wrong here and why am I failing??

Comment: What kind of phone? Does it have javascript? Comment out all of your code in getURL() and instead use alert('button click successful'). Test that on your phone and see if you get the alert.

Comment: I am testing from an iPhone 5. I thought about this last night and this is my next step. I agree I need to make sure the click event is even firing.